# Oracle 19 in Docker (WSL2) is much slower than a native Oracle 12 install on Windows

Tags: oracle, docker

I am attempting to run Oracle 19 inside a Docker container on Windows, but despite the usage of WSL2, I am still seeing an 80% drop in performance as compared to a natively installed Oracle 12 instance on the same machine.

Based on what I read on Docker blogs, I did not expect such a drastic drop in performance when running on WSL2. I am looking for some ideas as to what might be causing the slowdown.

Please note that Oracle 19 data is stored on the WSL2 filesystem, so nothing is bound to any host Windows directories:

```
$ docker container inspect --format '{{json .Mounts}}' oracle19_ubuntu_test
[
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "526a083007c33fb2ec59886191a7b975b2083d020b3714322e79abc51c77a55c",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/526a083007c33fb2ec59886191a7b975b2083d020b3714322e79abc51c77a55c/_data",
    "Destination": "/opt/oracle/oradata",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
]
```

Initially I noticed the slowdown when my test suite took 5 minutes longer to run against the dockerized Oracle instance. To figure out what's going on, I created another small test suite with 3 scenarios:

**1) JDBC Connection performance test**

This test repeatedly establishes a new JDBC connection and performs a small query that should not use any Disk I/O. This is done in a loop of 100 iterations and the total time is measured. This test attempts to measure the overhead of establishing a JDBC connection.

The test query:

```
select 1 from dual
```

This test runs 42% slower on Docker.

**2) Big Data Generate and Fetch test**

This test executes a query which generates a lot of data in memory, and then returns that data. This test measures query performance and JDBC transport time, hopefully without any disk I/O.

The test query:

```
select dbms_random.value(0, 10000000000) from dual connect by level <= 100000
```

This test runs 84% slower on Docker

**3) Big Data Fetch test**

This is a lot like Test #2, but the data is pre-generated and stored in `BIG_DATA` table, so this test measures just the query performance reading from a table, and JDBC transport time.

`BIG_DATA` table was pre-created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE BIG_TABLE (
  RN_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  RN_2 INTEGER NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO BIG_TABLE (RN_1, RN_2)
select 
  trunc(dbms_random.value(1,10000000000)) RN_1,
  trunc(dbms_random.value(1,10000000000)) RN_2 
from dual
connect by level <= 2000000;
```

And the test query:

```
SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE fetch first 100000 rows only
```

This test runs 83% slower in Docker.

**4) #2 and #3 with "Fetch Size" set to 100,000**

I also ran Tests #2 and #3 with Fetch Size set to `100,000` instead of the default `10`.

The queries ran about 16 times faster, with dockerized Oracle being noticeably faster than native Oracle!

Details of Fetch Size connection setting: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oraperf2.htm#1002425

**Details**

You can see specific timings in a nice table here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgHw23UQG_NbKKF7XuPm9JIFJQQckTGtEJY_DPDkNwY

You can see the JUnit code that runs the above 3 tests here:
https://gitlab.com/vace117/oracle-19-docker-wsl2-performance/-/blob/master/src/test/java/vace117/jdbc/JdbcConnectionTests.java

**Observations**

At first I suspected the problem might be with the network stack. The reasons I thought that might be the case:

- Heavy operations that run inside the db (such as generation of data for `BIG_TABLE`) actually run slightly faster on dockerized Oracle 19 than they do on native Oracle 12. So it's not at all slow, once the operation is running inside the database.
- Test #1 that simply opens and closes JDBC connections is 42% slower for Docker
- Test #2 and Test #3 are equally slower on docker (~ 83%), even though one test has disk I/O and the other does not. What they have in common is sending the data back over the JDBC connection.

However, the fact that increasing the `Fetch Size` on the connection makes dockerized Oracle work so much faster seems to suggest that it is not the network transfer speed, but rather something to do with the way Oracle chunks up the data and prepares it for transfer over the JDBC connection?

I think that this observation might be key to zeroing in on the problem... To summarize: we have a query that fetches lots of data. This query runs fast on native Oracle 12, regardless of Fetch Size. However, in dockerized Oracle 19, this setting suddenly has a huge impact on performance, with higher `Fetch Size` leading to significantly higher performance. **Can anyone explain this observation?**

**Test System Setup**

- Windows: `Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1082)`
- Docker: `20.10.0, build 7287ab3`
- Native Oracle: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`
- Docker Oracle: `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 Production`

**Oracle 19 Image**

The Oracle 19 image was built using the official Dockerfile provided here:
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles

The following settings were modified in `'docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0/dbca.rsp.tmpl'`:

```
createAsContainerDatabase=false
totalMemory=16384
```

The total memory allocation was cranked up to unreasonable levels, just to eliminate any potential SGA and PGA memory issues. `V$PGASTAT` and `V$SGASTAT` views were used to verify that PGA and SGA limits are indeed set very high (much higher than my Native Oracle 12 instance).

I have also verified that the Oracle's docker container has access to all CPUs and 26G of RAM.

Looking for some general thoughts/ideas/validation/refutation of my hypothesis. What could be causing the slowness in my setup? Is network stack a likely candidate based on the evidence I presented?

Comment: Where do you run your tests from ? Using the client from your docker Oracle installation ? Using a separate client in WSL ? Or using an Oracle client in Windows ? What your tests indicate is that network connections between an Oracle client and the dockerized Oracle server are slow. It could be a generic issue with the network stack in this environment ...

Comment: For the fetches, how big is the array used?  It's quite important to fetch a significant number of records at once.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Thank you for confirming my suspicion that network might be the bottleneck here. My tests run on the Windows host, talking to the Docker container using a port on localhost. This does give me an idea - I could confirm that it is the network stack by running the same tests from a WSL2 distro instead of the host. If the tests are faster there, then it's definitely the network! I'll set that up next week and post results here.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I am not sure I understand the question... By "array", do you mean the number of records I'm fetching? If so, I am fetching 100,000 records in my tests. But why does it matter? Since I am running exactly the same test against my 2 databases and observing different results, why would the size of my data set matter? I picked 100,000 rows b/c in the "slow" environment that returns in about 8 seconds.

Comment: It matters immensely. It's a setting on connection level. Fetching 100k records 10 at a time or 1000 at a time. For someone running performance tests, this information may be of interest. Also: give it a try on Linux.

Comment: Here's the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oraperf2.htm#1002425.  BTW, thanks for showing what a waste of resources containers are.

Comment: As Gerald mentioned batching matters a lot when it comes to network overhead. Not just for reading. Batching for insertions can deliver more than 10 fold better throughput, comparing single inserts with inserts in batches of 10000. 

But the question in your case remains to understand what makes your network connections so much slower when connection from  windows client to a docker image on the same machine.

Comment: I don’t recall seeing any difference between running a database natively on a Linux server and running a database in a docker container on the same Linux server. But then Docker runs natively without needing any supporting VM. Things are different on Windows or Mac where Docker containers run in a VM. But I have not seen a difference between running a database in a docker container and a database in a Linux VM - on the same Mac. I can’t say anything about Windows and WSL but I would expect the container to run natively in WSL.

Comment: I actually have done exactly the same test on my Linux machine as well. The problem is not present there. Dockerized Oracle runs only slightly (and acceptably) slower vs a native Oracle instance. Pretty sure this is going to be a "Docker on Windows" problem.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the link to the docs! I did not know about the "Fetch Size" parameter, and that one looks looks very useful to know about. It gives me another idea of how to confirm that it really is the network. My tests are currently going to the db every 10 rows, so if I increase "Fetch Size" significantly, I should also see a corresponding improvement in performance, thus further cementing the notion that network is the bottleneck in my setup.

Comment: Just tried setting "Fetch Size" on my connection to 100,000. The test went from taking 8 seconds to taking half a second :). So what does this result actually mean? We still transfer the same amount of data over the supposedly "slow" Docker network, but now its 16 times faster, b/c we are not establishing a new connection every 10 rows? So it's not transfer speed that's slow, but network socket creation?

Comment: Damn - it seems that running my tests from inside a WSL2 distro will not be possible. The group policies enforced by my employer seem to make it very non-obvious how to get anything inside WSL2 container to talk to anything outside. Can't even ping the host  so no way to access my databases either :(

Comment: "network socket creation".  That would really harm any transfer, even on Linux.  Can you check if there is any means to keep the connection open, socket reuse or something?  Also, could you try different fetch sizes, starting with a 100?  Just to find the optimum.

Comment: Unless you're sure about the group policies, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633406/unable-to-access-network-from-wsl2

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for looking that up, but in my case the issue is the Windows Defender Firewall, which I cannot turn off or reconfigure due to Group Policies. There are a lot of issues logged about this problem: 
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4139, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4619 . There are some workarounds suggested in those issues, but none of them seem to work on my laptop :(.

Comment: OK.  So, about reusing existing connection/socket?  Does Windows allow you to run Wireshark on that fetch?  It probably won't, since no real NIC is involved.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Once I realized that connection establishment might be the issue, I re-ran my primary big test suite (not the tiny one with those test queries) with a pooling datasource and verified that the same 3 connections were used to execute all of my tests (tens of thousands of them). No performance gain was observed when using the pooling datasource. I am not sure how to interpret that... On the one hand we have the fact that increasing the Fetch Size clearly boosts performance. On the other hand we can see no performance gain from re-using the same JDBC connections.

Comment: The test where performance was drastically increased by increasing the Fetch Size was using a single JDBC connection in both cases. That seems to suggest that the bottle neck is somewhere inside Oracle's code that is responsible for chunking up data sets? Really grasping at straws here :)

Comment: No, that would be when your application has connects strewn all over the place, but also on webservers answering thousands of requests. Establishing a connection is one of the heaviest actions executed by the database, apart from bad design and SQL.

Comment: I think my use of a pooled datasource eliminates the suspicion of connection establishment being the bottle neck, right? Only 4 connections were established and re-used to run all of the tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118026/discussion-between-val-blant-and-gerard-h-pille).

Comment: I have some new test results from WSL2. I got a co-worker to run the same tests (both the real test suite and my 3 little tests) on his personal Windows machine where he was able to turn off the firewall. Contrary to my expectation, everything was EVEN SLOWER when executing from a WSL2 distro. I think this disproves my theory about the bottleneck having to do with Docker network stack. I guess I am back to square 1 - no idea why Oracle 19 running in Docker is so slow :(

Comment: As a workaround one can move back to a HyperV backend for Docker on Windows, performance is almost native for Oracle 18c XE at least.